# GNOME bad font rendering

Tags: fedora, gnome, fonts

I'm on Fedora 33. No matter which font I use, not even which settings I choose (hinting style, antialias mode, ecc.), the font rendering is just a mess. Take a look at this picture:

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/Fedora_33_with_its_default_desktop_environment_%28GNOME_3.38%29_and_background.png]

For example, the word "Region" looks like "Re gi on". This seems to be a kerning issue and it's present in every app (BUT Chrome, which has a perfet rendering).

Any idea?

Comment: GNOME switched away from OpenType in F32 and the new font rendering system is still pretty bad.  Hopefully in F34 they’ll get all the harfbuzz bugs worked out.

Comment: I just noticed that KDE apps, under GNOME, have a PERFECT font rendering: is there a way to make GTK apps use the same settings?

Comment: So, it’s a “pango” library thing, which KDE doesn’t use.